# $.GET to localhost in Rails. Temporary solution for 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cross-domain

I'm creating a little frontend that gets .json files from my rails application. I've got the frontend detached from the application. Because that's how it will work when it will go online.

When it will be online, however, the domain will be the same; Thus there's no crossdomain call problem at that point. Now, in development on localhost, there is.

I know of gems like Middleman and such. Is that the way to go to avoid errors like `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/groups/1/activities.json. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Or is there a short workaround which I can use while I'm in development mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have following headers added on the backend side

```
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
```

Comment: which browser you using?chrome?

Comment: Yes I'm using Chrome.

Comment: start chrome with the --disable-web-security flag

Comment: That's plenty for my situation. Peter Goldstein's answer is worth a shot too though(For anyone reading this :p )

Answer (score 1):

You can use rack-cors - https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors .  Takes about 10 minutes to set up.

Comment: Does this work for Windows? I've got Linux aswell but prefer cross-platform since I'm working on both.

Comment: Should be completely cross-platform.  Windows, Linux, Mac, whatever.  Goes in the Rails app.